# D3.JS: Making plotted line static wrt axis in a 2D plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I am beginner in D3 and don't know a lot about it.
I am currently trying to plot a 2D line on a graph using D3. I have been successfully able to plot the line, add axis , and even add zoom capabilities to the plot.

I am stuck in making the line hinged to y axis such that you can't just click on it and move it left or right (Currently if you would run the jsfiddle you could click on it and move the plotted line). I would still want to zoom in or out . But it should remain hinged to the y axis. Please let me know if this clarifies my issue.
Thanks!

Link to JS fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/adityap16/4sts8nfs/2/

Code

```
var data = [{
  "mytime": "2015-12-01T23:10:00.000Z",
  "value": 64
}, {
  "mytime": "2015-12-01T23:15:00.000Z",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "mytime": "2015-12-01T23:20:00.000Z",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "mytime": "2015-12-01T23:25:00.000Z",
  "value": 64
}, {
  "mytime": "2015-12-01T23:30:00.000Z",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "mytime": "2015-12-01T23:35:00.000Z",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "mytime": "2015-12-01T23:40:00.000Z",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "mytime": "2015-12-01T23:45:00.000Z",
  "value": 80
}, {
  "mytime": "2015-12-01T23:50:00.000Z",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "mytime": "2015-12-01T23:55:00.000Z",
  "value": 86
}, {
  "mytime": "2015-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  "value": 80
}, {
  "mytime": "2015-12-02T00:05:00.000Z",
  "value": 85
}];
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.mytime = parseDate(d.mytime);
});
//var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40, left:50 },
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 50
  },
  height = 200,
  width = 900;
var color = "green";
var xaxis_param = "mytime";
var yaxis_param = "value";
var params1 = {
  margin: margin,
  height: height,
  width: width,
  color: color,
  xaxis_param: xaxis_param,
  yaxis_param: yaxis_param
};

draw_graph(data, params1);

function draw_graph(data, params) {

  var make_x_axis = function() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x_scale)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(5);
  };

  var make_y_axis = function() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y_scale)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5);
  };

  //Get the margin
  var xaxis_param = params.xaxis_param;
  var yaxis_param = params.yaxis_param;
  var color_code = params.color;
  var margin = params.margin;
  var height = params.height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    width = params.width - margin.left - margin.right;

  var x_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d[xaxis_param]
  });

  var y_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d[yaxis_param]
  });

  var x_scale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(x_extent)
    .range([0, width]);

  var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, y_extent[1]])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x_scale)
    .y(y_scale)
    .on("zoom", zoomed);


  //Line
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) {
      return d[yaxis_param];
    })
    .x(function(d) {
      return x_scale(d[xaxis_param]);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y_scale(d[yaxis_param]);
    });

  var lineRef = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x_scale(d[xaxis_param]);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y_scale(20);
    });

  var myChart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'graph')
    .style('background', '#E7E0CB')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
    .call(zoom);

   myChart.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "plot");


  var legend = myChart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 5 + "," + (height - 25) + ")")

  legend.append("rect")
    .style("fill", color_code)
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 20);

  legend.append("text")
    .text(yaxis_param)
    .attr("x", 25)
    .attr("y", 12);


  var vAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y_scale)
    .orient('left')
    .ticks(5)


  var hAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x_scale)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(5);

  var majorAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x_scale)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(d3.time.day, 1)
    .tickSize(-height)
    .outerTickSize(0);

  myChart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(hAxis);

  myChart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis major")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(majorAxis);

  myChart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(vAxis);

  var circlePoint = myChart.selectAll('circle')
                         .data(data)
                         .enter()
                         .append("circle");

    var circleAttributes = circlePoint
                           .attr("cx", function (d) { return x_scale(d[xaxis_param]); })
                           .attr("cy", function (d) { return y_scale(d[yaxis_param]); })
                           .attr("r", 3)
                           .style("fill", "none")
                           .style("stroke", "red");

    var clip = myChart.append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

    var chartBody = myChart.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");



chartBody.append("svg:path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr('stroke', color_code)
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr('fill', 'none');

  chartBody
    .append('svg:path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('class', 'line1')
    .attr("d", lineRef)
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
    .attr('fill', 'none');

  function zoomed() {
    myChart.select(".x.axis").call(hAxis);
    myChart.select(".y.axis").call(vAxis);
    myChart.select(".x.axis.major").call(majorAxis);
    myChart.select(".line")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
    myChart.select(".line1")
        .attr("class", "line1")
        .attr("d", lineRef);


  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this `.on("mousedown.zoom", null)` to disable panning:

```
 var myChart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'graph')
    .style('background', '#E7E0CB')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
    .call(zoom)
        .on("mousedown.zoom", null);//disable panning
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qx6w4ft3/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Also how can i just zoon in x axis and remove the y axis zoom?

Comment: Surely he wants to keep panning? Zoom's no good if you can't then pan...

Comment: I don't think the graph will look correct if i disable the y zoom.